# Rails + Haml: How to unescape tag parameter?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm trying to accomplish the following content in source code:

```
<div id="box<%=id%>"></div>
```

Without escaping any signs in Haml.

```
%div{ :id => "box_<%=id%>" }
```

produces

```
<div id='box_&lt;%=id%&gt;'></div>
```

Right now the only way I can do this with Haml is to use `:plain` filter and hardcode HTML without using any View Helpers. How can I fix that?

I need this because I'm forced to follow this convention because of third-party syntax convention: [JavaScript Micro-Templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/)

Reference:

[Haml reference](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you're coding in Haml, but the brackets indicate Erb.

- **Step 1**. Try normal Ruby interpolation:

  ```
  %div{ :id => "box_#{id}" }
  ```
- **Step 2**. There is no step 2.

**Update**: When I wrote this answer, I had not used a JS templating framework before. My apologies for not grokking why this was necessary.

Comment: Sorry but I don't code. I code in Haml and need <%=id%> unescaped in source code(Micro-Templating link explains the syntax). David, how can I fix that?

Comment: I'm confused. You're generating a template for one language to parse using *another* templating language? I don't think I would go this route.

Comment: Right :) Probably Micro-Templating link will explain it better.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to disagree with you. John Resig's Micro-Templating works well for me just like for many other people. And I can not refuse it. The question was not about whether it is a good or not.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, just don't use HAML for that one statement. For example, assuming you are doing something like this in HAML right now:

```
%script#template(type="text/html")
    %div{ :id => "box_<%=id%>" }
```

Instead, do:

```
%script#template(type="text/html")
    <div id="box_<%=id%>"></div>
```

It will interpret the script tag as HAML correctly, then since you aren't using any `%`, `#`, etc. to start the next line it will interpret that line as plain text and pass it through. Seems to work fine for me and I have a very similar case to yours. The one thing I did do was change the jQote (the templating engine I'm using for my Javascript templating) tag from `%` to `$` with this Javascript statement in the `head` of the page:

```
%script( type="text/javascript")
    $(function() { $.jqotetag( '$' ); });
```

That way the `%` signs don't confuse the Ruby interpreter. So the final example would be:

```
%script#template(type="text/html")
    <div id="box_<$=id$>"></div>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#unescaping_html

```
! %div(id="box_<%= data.id %>")
```

Comment: solves the problem in half way. In my case, I need to do ! <div id="box_<%= data.id %>"></div>